# How exactly wordpiece embeddings deal with OOV tokens?

Tags: nlp, word-embedding, transformer-model

I understand how wordpiece tokenization works, for instance, if the word "mocking" and "walked" are very frequent in corpus the model is trained upon and so they will be split into subwords as ["walk","##ed"] and ["mock","##ing"] respectively. Let say the model encounters the word "walking" which is an OOV token, so wordpiece would split this into ["walk","##ing"] and it will be able to make some sense out of this. This is my understanding, I might be wrong so please forgive me for that.

But this is where I'm confused, if there's another OOV token, "mockingjay" for instance, how will wordpiece handle it? Will it break it into ["mock","##ing","##jay"] ? will it consider it similar to "mocking"?

and FYI, I asked ChatGPT the same thing and this what it said -

`If the model is familiar with the concept of mocking, it may still interpret "Mockingjay" as a separate token rather than splitting it into "Mocking" and "jay." However, it ultimately depends on the specific tokenizer and its vocabulary. Different tokenizers may have different strategies for handling specific words, and the behavior can be influenced by the training data and the context in which the tokenization is performed.`